# <sqlite3.Row object at > in database foreign key

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

[image]

books.book_id = primary key

chapters.book_id = foreign key

Should my chapters.book_id look the way it does in the picture?

When I do an inner join

```
cur = db.execute("SELECT books.title, chapters.chapter FROM books INNER JOIN chapters ON books.book_id=chapters.book_id")
```

I just get `[]` printed out on screen

This code inserts the data from an html form to my database

```
@app.route('/newbook')
def new_book():
    return render_template('newbook.html')

@app.route('/addbook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addbook():
    db = get_db()
    db.execute("INSERT INTO books (title) VALUES (?)", 
        [request.form['title']])
    db.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('new_chapter'))


@app.route('/newchapter')
def new_chapter():
    return render_template('newchapter.html')

@app.route('/addchapter', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addchapter():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute("SELECT last_insert_rowid()")
    book_id = cur.fetchone()
    db.execute("INSERT INTO chapters (chapter, book_id) VALUES (?, ?)", [request.form['chapter'], str(book_id)])
    db.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('new_concepts'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A query returns a table-like object with (potentially) many rows and columns.

Iterating over a cursor, or calling `fetchone()`, returns a row in each step.

A row is a tuple containing all column values. Even when there is a single column, its value is still wrapped in a tuple.

To get a single value from a query, you have to extract it from the tuple:

```
book_id = db.execute("SELECT last_insert_rowid()").fetchone()[0]
#                                                            ^^^
```

---

Please note that the return value of `last_insert_rowid()` changes after inserting the chapter, so when you insert a second chapter for the same book, it will blow up. You have to read the book ID immediately after inserting the book (and the cursor's [`lastrowid` attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.lastrowid) is simpler to use).